# Transition Forward is going backward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a newbie to unity. In my project, the ball should instantiate in the player

position and it should go randomly 40 to 120 degrees from the player position.

I am using transition.forward. My player is constantly in running. when the player stands the ball is going correctly in front of the player.

but when the player runs the ball is going backward

How can I move towards randomly in front of the player? Like a ball

I am using the below code.

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*5f );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance it might be fixed if you spawn the ball in front of the character. Since it works when the player is stationary, it might be conflicting with the collider of player when it is moving.

Also translating will just move the ball, not give it a velocity or anything. You should take a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

So, first translate the ball forward and see if it spawned in the right location.

Then add a force vector to the ball's rigid body in the direction you like.

Something like:

```
ball.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*5f);
float thrust = 10;
var rb = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.AddForce(transform.forward * thrust);
```